# Displaying poll results in pie chart format in drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal-7

Instead of displaying default result format, i need to display in Pie chart format results.

i have got [chart module](https://drupal.org/project/chart)

but how to integrate with poll result page.

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement function

```
yourtemplate_preprocess_poll_results(&$variables)
```

to add your modifications and override poll-results.tpl.php in your template.

Regards

Comment: You're welcome. I´ll be grateful if you mark the answer as "accepted" in case it resolve your problem. Thank you. :)